# Position (background of) div outside container, but keep content aligned with page container

Tags: html, css

I would like to accomplish this design with only HTML & CSS.

[image]

It has to be full responsive, meaning:

1. The light grey div on the left, must be responsive and have a fixed padding-top and padding-bottom, depending on the content. ( if content becomes higher because of smaller screen sizes, the padding must remain and the div must grow ( together with the right div with the image ) ).
2. The light grey div on the left, must go outside the container, to the far left and fill the entire screen ( on the left side ). BUT the content of this div must align within the container of the page div.
3. The image on the right, must have the same size and the light grey div on the left, and contain an image, centered within the div.

Problems I encountered when trying, **see link for code**:

- Adding a sibling div, next to the div with the content, and position absolute to the left of the screen with z-index -10. This div had no idea of the height of the content, so the paddings are not responsive. [play tailwindcss](https://play.tailwindcss.com/GEP00Qa8M2)
- When adding the position absolute on the div with the content itself, I cannot align the content with the container of the rest of the page. [play tailwindcss](https://play.tailwindcss.com/k5XOiAax1c)

... out of ideas. Any help?

Comment: Didn't downvote, but in general adding code to show what you have tried and to make it easier to find a solution would be great. Right now, this feels like a "build my layout" question to me. Also, you are talking about a light grey div on the left and a grey div on the left. I am only seeing one div on the left? I don't really understand that one.

Comment: Thanks @Maharkus I will update my question in a minute.